# Preceding Zeros on Numbers (With Letters on Some)

Tags: printf

an awful post title I know, struggled with that one!

Basically I have a list of numbers ranging from 1 - 230(ish)

I'm using `sprintf( '%03d', $num)` to output the numbers so that they have preceding zeros if necessary.

However something has buggered it all up, as I see some of the numbers also have letters in them (e.g. 134a, 134b etc).

So those numbers all currently output as '134'

I tried setting `sprintf` to `%04d` but that didn't work either, it just displayed them as '0134'

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like hexadecimal numbers.  Use "%04x".

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to work unfortunately, it turns 134a to 0086 and 143 to 008f etc